# Combining multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I've got this in-line view that is combining two tables via a natural join. I have a few conditions on it to make the view more manageable.

```
Select * from student
natural join course
where student.stuNo = '838637'
and course.crsno = 'CS201'
```

Now, I am wanting to do a left outer join from this view with another table.  I'm getting an error message and for the life of me I can't figure out how to fix it.  This is my last snipplet:

```
Select * from score2
left outer join (
Select * from student
natural join course
where student.stuNo = '838637'
and course.crsno = 'CS201') as Test1
on Test1.stuno = score2.studentNO
```

The error message says I'm missing a keyword, but I can't figure out where.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `AS` shouldn't be there:

```
Select * from score2
left outer join (
Select * from student
natural join course
where student.stuNo = '838637'
and course.crsno = 'CS201') Test1
on (Test1.stuno = score2.studentNO)
```

Comment: What the deuce. I tried that and I was still getting the error.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the reminder.  I tried after Przemyslaw answered but it was too soon apparently.  I just forgot about it due to work.  Thanks.